# Extracting path of all PNG on website to Excel file

Tags: excel, csv, png, extract

Guys is there any possibilities to get all list of png on website(full path) to Excel file?? I dont know how to do automate this process. Maybe there is some software? Will apreciate your helP!! THanks

Answer (score 0):

If the webserver is running Windows:

```
cd <WEBROOT>
DIR *.PNG /B /S > allPNGs.csv
```

If the webserver is running Linux:

```
cd <WEBROOT>
find . -iname \*.png > allPMGs.csv
```

Comment: Thanks man, really helped me a lot. Im newcomer and cannot give you +